# Azure EventHub ConnectionStringBuilder not returning the correct connection string

Tags: azure-eventhub

I am trying to get started with Eventhubs using the following link https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/event-hubs-java-storm-getstarted/.

When I pass the connection string directly to the ConnectionStringBuilder( connectionString), then the program sends data to the Eventhub. I notice that the connection string

starts with Endpoint=sb://....

but when I use ConnectionStringBuilder(namespaceName, eventHubName, sasKeyName, sasKey), I notice that the connectionstring created

starts with Endpoint=amqps://

and the program doesn't work and gives the following error

```
com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.AuthorizationFailedException: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
```

Answer (score 0):

I missed the last char of the SaSKey and so It didn't work...Sorry for this question